# Logback ClassCastException for LoggerFactory

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, logback-classic

I am using below code to change log level at runtime in logback.

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
```

However I am getting ClassCastException with message:

```
org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
```

My pom has these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not able to figure out whats wrong here. I can see many examples using this code. But its not working for me. I want to change log level dynamically so I am using Logger class from classic instead of slf4j. Can anybody help me identifying where I am wrong?

Comment: If the dependencies are set to transitive (I think by default they are in maven) you should leave only the first one - logback-classic in the pom and remove the others and then try again. In addition try declaring your logger as `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root` because sometimes the IDE working in doesn't compile/clean compiles...